# Unable to use WooCommerce custom field as recipient in custom email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I'm trying to accomplish is to use custom fields from my checkout in a new custom email. I've found documentation on [returning the key, value within the body of the email](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-custom-field-in-an-order-to-the-emails/) and in order details, which works.

The problem is I can't get this to work with a new custom order notification, where I want to use 'back-up email' as the recipient of the custom email notification.

```
 /** WORKING
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys');

function my_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys['back-up email?'] = 'backup_email';
    return $keys;
}
/** WORKING
 * Add to back-end
 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
     echo '<p><strong>'.__('Back-up Email').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'backup_email', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

The custom email is created with this [tutorial](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/).

```
// Does not work
$this->recipient = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'backup_email', true );
// defaults to admin email
if ( ! $this->recipient )
        $this->recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
```

I'm probably missing some basic PHP/WP principals, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It needed to be called after setup of new order object

```
$this->object = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$this->recipient = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'backup_email', true );
```

I see this question has been asked a few times since, so hope it helps someone.